# Модальное окошко в стиле linux

Tags: jquery, html, css

Есть ли стиль для модальных окон, как в ОС Linux? Например для плагина UI-Dialog? Или другого какого-нибудь плагина.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вопрос задан немного некорректно, т.к. внешний вид окна зависит от графической оболочки. В частности, на том линуксе с которым я работаю ее совсем нет и окна там "не очень".
Что именно вас не устраивает в модальных окнах jquery-ui? Если это размеры шрифта, отступы, цвет, то у них на сайте есть [замечательная страничка](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), на которой вы можете все стили настроить по своему вкусу.